# Signalr - Customize Generated Content on Script signalr/hubs

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, signalr

I would like to customize the content found at /signalr/hubs.

So rather than just giving the standard JS proxy back, I would like that endpoint to generate something additional.

The business requirement is to build out on the script area:

proxies[\'myHub\'].client = { }

I would like to put down custom javascript that extends on the current generated javascript.

Comment: But why you want to do that? `SignalR` provides everything that you want to implement with `SignalR`. That's why you also can not find this file in the your project. I also don't know that we able to edit that file or not.

Comment: Signalr already generates the proxy JS code. I would like to have more control of the content.

Comment: But which type of control you want ? Please describe what you wants ?

Comment: The content as already specified is an JS Proxy. It is a simple proxy and I would like to add additional functionality. This content was derived of DTO classes and hubs within in the project signalr is running from.

So the additional behaviour is to add Javascript that would enhance the current standard vanilla JS Proxy. There is numerous things that I would love to add or have additional generated on this endpoint. They including conditional exclusion of section, conditional addition of sections. Additional JS function, and a lot more

Comment: But there is no another way to add this coding in the `Hubs` file or create your own `JS` files to implement this functionality. And `SignalR` uses the `WebScokets` for `Push notification` So you can also write your code to implements what you wants by the `WebSockets`.

Comment: You also can post your question on `SignalR` forum here: http://forums.asp.net/1254.aspx Post your question I sure you will get something helpful.

Comment: As far as I know Signalr is an OpenSource Library "

Comment: Thus I looked up this url :

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils/Commands/GenerateHubProxyCommand.cs

Would it mean that I have to rebuild the whole signalr just to do what I would like to do ?

Comment: Awesome.. Try it and post your review. But be careful to do that it may be disturb the other existing functionality. I wish you get success, If you get success you can re-publish that project on `github`Good Luck.